# How to say "cheat sheet" in French

Tags: traduction, anglais

How to say *cheatsheet* in French in the sense of Quick Reference Card and not of cheating in the exams?
For instance, here is a trigonometry cheat sheet

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/trig_cheat_sheet.pdf

I have seen *aide-mémoire* in linguee but an *aide-mémoire* can be also a complete book as for example

https://www.amazon.fr/Aide-m%C3%A9moire-R%C3%A9sistance-mat%C3%A9riaux-10e-%C3%A9d/dp/2100708392

so I am puzzled. I also found *antisèche* and *feuille de triche*.
The first seems to have a negative connotation (exam cheating) whereas the second seems to be more for the informatics.

Should we just say *formulaire*? The *cheatsheet* is colloquial in French?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Antisèche* is the litteral translate, but is generally used for real cheating at exam (like writing stuff on your arm).

If you just keep notes for yourself at work for example, the word *pense-bête* seems a better fit.

Comment: This is not correct: https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/antis%C3%A8che/4282 Cheat sheet is not this. It's an aide-memoire.

Comment: aide-mémoire is good, probably even better than pense-bête, when the goal is not cheating. But a cheat sheet can also be a real cheating tool (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheat_sheet ), in that case antisèche is the correct translation.

Answer (score 14):

**Une fiche aide-mémoire** is commonly used in Canadian French for that.

The term *fiche* refers to a small paper or carton that the note would be written on.

> [fiche](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/fiche): Petite feuille de carton sur laquelle on écrit soit les titres
>   des ouvrages que l’on veut cataloguer, soit les renseignements sur une
>   personne ou un fait que l’on veut garder et retrouver facilement.

Exemple d'usage de l'expression: [Fiche aide-mémoire](https://www.umoncton.ca/umcm-saee/node/445)

> La personne étudiante qui nécessite ***une fiche aide-mémoire*** lors
>   de son examen doit présenter un rapport d’évaluation professionnel au
>   Service d’accès et de soutien à l’apprentissage qui atteste la
>   présence d’un diagnostic et précise la nécessité d’***une fiche
>   aide-mémoire*** comme mesure d’adaptation pour ses examens.

Comment: In France we'd typically say « un aide-mémoire ».

Comment: @Gilles On le trouve au Qc. [aussi](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8352861). Rien à voir mais le GDT dit aussi qu' « aide-mémoire » est couramment utilisé en anglais... eh bien.

Comment: Dire aide-mémoire ou fiche aide-mémoire revient au même, non?

Comment: @Lambie Oui tout a fait, je trouvait juste fiche aide-mémoire plus précis dans le contexte de "cheat sheet". Je ne me souvient plus pourquoi j'en ai pas parlé dans ma réponse par contre.

Answer (score 1):

One can use also the word mémento. An example of usage can be found here: https://perso.limsi.fr/pointal/_media/python:cours:mementopython3.pdf